# How to render BindingResult in Spring web 5 (boot) like it does default error handler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I use `@RequestBody @Valid` annotations to validate JSON input argument for method in controller. It's web application serving API via spring-boot-starter-web 2.0.1.RELEASE.

When object validation finds error, default exception handler produces really nice JSON explaining what exactly is wrong with input.

The problem is that I have own `@ExceptionHandler` as my API has contract for failure messages. I want to incorporate Spring's validation JSON structure under my own JSON that would wrap it.

In my custom exception hanlder I see that I receieve `MethodArgumentNotValidException` but I don't know how to deserialize it to JSON the same way as Spring does internally. Apparently, in Spring there is some class that does it.

Could somebody give a hint?

Below example of JSON that I want to be part of my object

```
{
    "timestamp" : "2018-05-01T22:45:28.907+0000",
    "status" : 400,
    "error" : "Bad Request",
    "errors" : [{
            "codes" : ["NotNull.ticket.items[0].amount", "NotNull.ticket.items.amount", "NotNull.items[0].amount", "NotNull.items.amount", "NotNull.amount", "NotNull.java.math.BigDecimal", "NotNull"],
            "arguments" : [{
                    "codes" : ["ticket.items[0].amount", "items[0].amount"],
                    "arguments" : null,
                    "defaultMessage" : "items[0].amount",
                    "code" : "items[0].amount"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage" : "may not be null",
            "objectName" : "ticket",
            "field" : "items[0].amount",
            "rejectedValue" : null,
            "bindingFailure" : false,
            "code" : "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "message" : "Validation failed for object='ticket'. Error count: 1",
    "path" : "/v1/databases/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/retail/pos/ticket"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a library method that solves this. I omitted rendering `arguments` as it's too much effort.

```
List<Map> validationErrors = new ArrayList<>();
BindingResult result = ((MethodArgumentNotValidException) e).getBindingResult();
for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
    Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
    res.put("codes", error.getCodes());
    res.put("defaultMessage", error.getDefaultMessage());
    res.put("objectName", error.getObjectName());
    res.put("field", error.getField());
    res.put("rejectedValue", error.getRejectedValue());
    res.put("bindingFailure", error.isBindingFailure());
    res.put("code", error.getCode());
    validationErrors.add(res);
}
for (ObjectError error : result.getGlobalErrors()) {
    Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
    res.put("codes", error.getCodes());
    res.put("defaultMessage", error.getDefaultMessage());
    res.put("objectName", error.getObjectName());
    res.put("code", error.getCode());
    validationErrors.add(res);
}

// now attach validationErrors to object
```